# Favorite Tags list on every page

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, tag-watching

It will be cool if I will have access to my Favorite Tags from every page of SO.

For me it is most useful feature after my profile page.

My ordinary use case is loading SO page and reading some from my favorite tags, but now it is quite complicated adventure: I should return to main page where all my favorite tags lives, or I should go to my profile, or I should find interested tags among tags I am visiting. And I hate to use "relative tags" because it makes chain search.

Favorite tags can be added as link at the top with dropdown, or the same way as in main page or anyway you like :)

**I am talking about access to LIST of all my `Favorite Tags` on every page**

Comment: I have to agree with you on this one.  I rely on my favorite tags list to navigate quickly.  In some cases, the favorite tags list appears on the bottom right underneath the long list of 'Related' posts causing me to scroll to bottom of page in order to navigate to my desired tag:  2 steps instead of 1.  Inefficient and quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere you see a tag, you can:

- mouse over the tag
- wait for the tag popup to appear
- **click the star** to favorite and un-favorite.

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/tag-favorites-subscribe2.png))</sub>

Comment: Sorry, but I am talking about list of all my favourite tags