# Do we really need the "favorite tags" panel to display on each question list?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-watching

The "favorite tags" list takes a very important and potentially very large real-estate on the screen. As an example, here's a screenshot of my current favorites on [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), which takes the entire area [above the fold](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/fold.php):

[image: my favorite tags]

And that's not even counting the ignored tags!

Now, I realize that [for some users having the favorite tags list readily available is apparently very convenient](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83409/favorite-tags-list-on-every-page), and indeed on a larger site like stackoverflow browsing according to favorite tags is probably very common; but on the smaller sites I have a feeling it's pretty rare - I never do it - and this wastes a lot of screen real-estate in a way which seems awfully wasteful to me.

Is it possible perhaps to give registered users an option to hide this part, or maybe to change it to some sort of scrollable / expandable list?

Comment: At first, my thoughts were "How do you have anything not blue with so many favorite tags?", but then I notice that you don't have Witcher 2 or Minecraft in that list.

Comment: What else do you want to have there?

Comment: @Gilles nothing, perhaps? That will make the chat link higher (which is good for drawing people into chat), and it will remove [the ugly padding which appears at the bottom of the page](http://i.imgur.com/griNp.png).

Comment: @Gilles and maybe also [a link to the blog :)](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/link-to-blog-appearing-when-logged-out-but-not-when-logged-in)